# How can I clean up this Selection Sort function in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, refactoring, selection-sort

I just went through and converted a Selection Sort function written in C++ to Python.

I feel like I'm coding this too much like a C programmer, whereas I know Python has many in-built functions to use with for loops that would clean it up. I'm just not sure where to start.

What things could I change in this code to make it more idiomatic?

```
def selection_sort(A):
    for i in range(0, len(A) - 1):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
            if A[j] < A[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
        if min_idx != i:
            A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]

    return A
```

Comment: If your code works, you should ask for further advice on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code actually looks very pythonic already! Noteworthy, you swap values with the `x, y = y, x` idiom, this is highly encouraged in Python.

Both Python2 and Python3:

- `range(0, x)` is equivalent to `range(x)`
- Optionally, you can lookup the minimum value index with `A.index(min(A[i:]))`. This is largely dependent on taste and with very large lists it will be slower. IMHO looks nice and concise:

```
def selection_sort(A):
    for i in range(0, len(A) - 1):
        min_idx = A.index(min(A[i:]))
        if min_idx != i:
            A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]

    return A
```

Python2:

- `range` makes a list - iterates over all elements - right away, `xrange` makes a lazy generator - iterates over the elements only when they're called for - it's preferred and often faster (it's not faster in the snippet you provided).

General:

- In a professional code review, you might be required to provide a docstring, roughly similar to:

```
def selection_sort(A):
    """selection_sort performs an unstable in-place sort on A

    A -- list to be sorted.

    Returns A, sorted.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(A) - 1):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
            if A[j] < A[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
        if min_idx != i:
            A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]

    return A
```

Sources:

- [`range` (Python2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)
- [`range` (Python3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [`xrange` (Python2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)
- [Docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)

Comment: Using a colon delimiter and the .index() function in the line `min_idx = A.index(min(A[i:]))` makes it much nicer to read. The docstrings source is much appreciated as well.

Thanks so much!